# npm run restore failed

Tags: npm, nuget

I was running npm run restore after init.cmd in my project.

npm is looking for contents under incorrect folders.

I got the following error. Would appreciate some help.

Unable to find version '8.305.0.5' of package 'Microsoft.Portal.Tools'.
C:\Users....nuget\packages: Package 'Microsoft.Portal.Tools.8.305.0.5' is not found on source 'C:\Users....nuget\packages'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages: Package 'Microsoft.Portal.Tools.8.305.0.5' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'.
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Microsoft.Portal.Tools.8.305.0.5' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

Unable to find version '5.1.0.19' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.Gallery.AzureGalleryUtility'.
C:\Users....nuget\packages: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.Gallery.AzureGalleryUtility.5.1.0.19' is not found on source 'C:\Users....nuget\packages'.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.Gallery.AzureGalleryUtility.5.1.0.19' is not found   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.Gallery.Common.5.1.0.19' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages'.  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.Gallery.Common.5.1.0.19' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that we are missing some  in the nuget.config file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).